# Why This Procedure Throws 'Unknown Column' Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have This Procedure but this throws 'Unknown Column' Error

```
USE dhod;
DELIMETER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_drive_size(IN uname VARCHAR(100),IN size INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE dsize INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE new_size INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT drive_size INTO dsize FROM profile WHERE username = uname;
    SET new_size=dsize+size;
    UPDATE profile SET drive_size=new_size WHERE username = uname; 
END @@ 
DELIMETER ;
```

I am Getting This Error
**Unknown column 'uname' in 'where clause'**

Answer (score 1):

Here is your original code

```
USE dhod;
DELIMETER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_drive_size(IN uname VARCHAR(100),IN size INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE dsize INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE new_size INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT drive_size INTO dsize FROM profile WHERE username = uname;
    SET new_size=dsize+size;
    UPDATE profile SET drive_size=new_size WHERE username = uname; 
END @@ 
DELIMETER ;
```

Would you believe you misspelled DELIMETER ???

It should be DELIMITER (I would change it to $$)

```
USE dhod;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_drive_size(IN uname VARCHAR(100),IN size INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE dsize INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE new_size INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT drive_size INTO dsize FROM profile WHERE username = uname;
    SET new_size=dsize+size;
    UPDATE profile SET drive_size=new_size WHERE username = uname; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: And I guess `END @@` should change to `END $$` in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: try getting rid of the starting and end @@delimiter to see if that fixes it? Examples i'm finding on the web only have delimiter at the top, but haven't seen examples including the second one at the bottom.